# システムメンテナンス時のサービス再起動について

Tags: centos

CentOS 6系上にて、apache+tomcat+postgresで構築したWEBサービスを複数稼動させています。それぞれが異なるIPアドレスを持ったマシンで動作しています。

現在のワークフローでは、各サイトをメンテナンスする際に、それぞれのサーバにログインしてコマンドラインから手動でserviceコマンドでtomcatを再起動させています。

現状の運用方法では、プロンプトに表示されたホストネームでログインしているサーバを識別するしかなく、メンテナンス予定でないサービスを再起動してしまうヒューマンリスクがあります。

意識的な問題かもしれませんが、未然に防ぐような仕組みやツールなどありましたらご教授いただきたいです。

Comment: 「サービスコマンド」とか「番組」とか内部の用語ではなく一般的な用語を使用された方が良いでしょう。また、「システム」「サイト」というのは文脈によって解釈が異なりますので、より限定された言葉に書き換えるなり、具体的な例を出したりするなりしたほうがよいです。

Comment: 同じシステム(１つのマシン)が、複数の別々のサイト（複数の異なるIPアドレスを持つサーバプログラム）を稼働させているという事でしょうか？　再起動時に、再起動予定サービスであるか否かをチェックするというのは可能(例えば、起動予定サービスのホストネーム一覧をファイルに入れておき、ログイン中のホストネームがファイルに含まれなければ、警告を出す等）だと思いますが、これも一覧のファイルの管理が悪ければ機能しません。　もう少し、運用などを具体的に説明されてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 「サービスコマンド」はひょっとして `service` コマンドのことでしょうか？

Comment: 回答するのが難しいと感じますので質問の改善を提案します。質問を読んだ人が、貴方の現在の状況を把握できるように、より具体的に書きなおしてみてください。例えば、システムの概要、OS、ネットワーク、運用体制、サイトの数、現在のワークフローなどです。書ける範囲で追記してみてください。そうすれば回答が付きやすくなりますよ。